# How to use try catch in a switch in a while

Tags: java

Program execution does not loop back once I run the code to read data.

Ive tried shifting where I place the try catch statements along with the finally statement and all manners of breaks continue.

```
    long code;
    char choice;


    Cars CarSales = new Cars(); //It creates a Java object and allocates memory for it on the heap.
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("   -----CARS SALES YARD------"); //The println is a method of java.io.PrintStream.
    do {
        System.out.println("1. Add item");
        choice = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
        switch (choice) {     //switch statement allows a variable to be tested for equality against a list of values. 
        case '6':
            try{
            CarSales.ReadData();
            continue;
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                     System.out.println("Error reading file '" );
                     continue;
            }
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Selection\n");
        }
    } while (choice != '6'); //while loop statement repeatedly executes a statement as long as a given condition is true
    sc.close();

public void ReadData() throws IOException{//This Method is in the Cars class
String fileName = "input.txt";
String line = null;
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
    }   
bufferedReader.close();   
System.out.println("TRY");
```

No error messages though program execution just stops looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By moving the `continue;` to **after** the `catch`. Like,

```
do {
    System.out.println("1. Add item"); //<-- where are 2-6?
    choice = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
    switch (choice) {
    case '6': // <-- don't forget case '1' - '5'
        try {
            CarSales.ReadData();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '");
        }
        continue; // <-- here, or a break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Selection\n");
    }
} while (choice != '6');
```